# Google maps. UI Drag control event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, drag

I'm using google maps API v3. 
I'm using the next code to create event callback for map dragging.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
        //Some Code...
    });
```

It works fine when I drag the map by mouse.
The issue is - "//Some Code" do not runs when I'm dragging map using UI controls (arrows) on the left top (default) of the map. The same is when I'm dragging the map using keyboard arrows.

And in reference I can't find anything like "UI drag control event" or "keyboard arrow button events".
Does anybody knows how can I handle such event?

Comment: you want to execute it always when the viewport of the map changes?

Comment: Only dragging. NO zoom_changed. And only after dragging was finished

Comment: dragging doesn't happen when the user uses the controls(it's called panning, the drag-events to not fire when panning via the controls)